# How to Run Magento 2 using pub/index.php file

Tags: magento2, configuration, security

How to Run Magento 2 using pub/index.php file.

We are going to point the site at pub/index.php for security point of view.

Can any one help us on how to configure this and steps to be taken care.

We found some information [here](https://darshanbhavsar.wordpress.com/2015/02/04/how-to-run-magento-2-using-pubindex-php-file/) but not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you just need to **point your VirtualHost to the `pub` folder instead of pointing it to the root folder.**